# Is this sql syntax correct?

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, sum, isnull

Can i apply `SUM()` within an `ISNULL()`.... Consider my following sql server select statement

```
SELECT e.Emp_Id,e.Identity_No,e.Emp_Name,case WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1 
THEN 'Weekly' ELSE 'Monthly' end as SalaryBasis,e.FixedSalary,
    ISNULL(Adv.Daily_Wage,0) as Advance from Employee as e 
    inner join Designation as d on e.Desig_Id=d.Desig_Id
    Left Outer Join Payroll as Adv on e.Emp_Id=Adv.Emp_Id where e.Is_Deleted=0
```

This Statement Works fine.... But when i apply `SUM()` within an `ISNULL()`

```
SELECT e.Emp_Id,e.Identity_No,e.Emp_Name,case WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1 
    THEN 'Weekly' ELSE 'Monthly' end as SalaryBasis,e.FixedSalary,
        ISNULL(SUM(Adv.Daily_Wage),0) as Advance from Employee as e 
        inner join Designation as d on e.Desig_Id=d.Desig_Id
        Left Outer Join Payroll as Adv on e.Emp_Id=Adv.Emp_Id 
        where e.Is_Deleted=0
```

I got the error,

> Column 'Employee.Emp_Id' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any suggestion....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to GROUP BY the other columns in the select. Something like

```
SELECT  e.Emp_Id,
        e.Identity_No,
        e.Emp_Name,
        case 
            WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1  THEN 'Weekly' 
            ELSE 'Monthly' 
        end as SalaryBasis,e.FixedSalary, 
        ISNULL(SUM(Adv.Daily_Wage),0) as Advance 
from    Employee as e  inner join 
        Designation as d on e.Desig_Id=d.Desig_Id Left Outer Join 
        Payroll as Adv on e.Emp_Id=Adv.Emp_Id  
where   e.Is_Deleted=0 
GROUP BY e.Emp_Id, --This section is what you are missing
        e.Identity_No,
        e.Emp_Name,
        case 
            WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1  THEN 'Weekly' 
            ELSE 'Monthly' 
        end,
    e.FixedSalary
```

Have a look at the definition here

[GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: the `case` in the `GROUP BY` *feels* inefficient to me... You can just as well group by `e.SalaryBasis` instead.